# Unable to retrieve the stored password from password vault

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, passwordvault

I have a UWP application that will get the username and password from the user and store it in the **password vault**. I am able to get the password from vault within the application. But, when I was trying to fetch the password through background task of the same application i got the exception says :

> Element Not Found cannot get credentials from vault.

I know password vault is unique to app or service, But why  it was unable to fetch the password through background task?

Comment: is the background task out-of-process or [in-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task)?

Comment: It is a out of process background task.

Comment: Just google around, this is a [supported scenario](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/07/25/offline-apps-what-to-do-when-your-user-disconnects/): _This is particularly helpful when using a background task to securely retrieve and store data for offline use since apps and services don’t have access to credentials associated with other apps or services._ Please provide the code you use in the BT to retrieve password from the vault.

Comment: I referenced the documentation in this URL "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue,  I have created sample that contain out process `BackgroudTask`, then fetch the password successfully, Please check if you have saved `PasswordCredential` successfully.

Comment: Yes password successfully saved in the vault. I can see the stored password in the credential manager.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: In store dump I got the exception like stowed_exception_80070490_vaultci.dll!vaultwinrtorginateerror